# Copying mysql data from one db to another with a where clause for a subset of tables

Tags: mysql, mysqldump

I'd like to be able to move mysql data from one db to another. I only want to move records `where account_id=1234` except for tables like `account` which does not have an `account_id` column.

Is there any possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

By "move" do you mean "copy"?  That is, are you leaving the rows behind?

**Two different machines**

`mysqldump` has options to specify particular a database and list of tables.  It also has an optional `WHERE` clause.  So...

```
mysqldump -h src -w "account_id=1234" -d db tbl1 tbl2 > some_tables.sql
mysqldump -h src -d db tbl3 tbl4 > other_tables.sql
```

(Please verify the syntax.)

Then load those two files into some other place (after doing `CREATE DATABASE newdb`):

```
mysql -h dest newdb <some_tables.sql
mysql -h dest newdb <other_tables.sql
```

**Same machine**

```
CREATE DATABASE newdb;
CREATE TABLE newdb.tbl1 LIKE db.tbl1;
INSERT INTO  newdb.tbl1 SELECT * FROM db.tbl1 WHERE account_id=1234;
 ditto for tbl2, etc
CREATE TABLE newdb.tbl3 LIKE db.tbl3;
INSERT INTO  newdb.tbl3 SELECT * FROM db.tbl3;
 ditto for tbl4, etc
```